# Conditionally populating a path in a Mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have the following schema:

```
const connectionSchema = new Schema( {
  ...
  event: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'events'
  },
  place: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'places'
  },
} )

const eventsSchema = new Schema( {
  ...
  place: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'places'
  },
} )
```

When I query for either a single `connection` or a collection of `connection`s, I want it to check if `event` is specified and if so return the `place` from the `event`, otherwise return the `place` from the `connection`.

I'm currently doing something like this when I'm querying a single connection:

```
let c
const execFunction = ( err, connection ) => {
  if ( connection.event ) {
    connection.place = connection.event.place
  }
  c = connection
}

const connectionPromise = Connection.findById( connectionId )
connectionPromise.populate( { path: 'event', populate: { path: 'place' } } )
connectionPromise.populate( 'place' )
connectionPromise.exec( execFunction )
```

But, I'm trying to avoid having to iterate through the entire collection in the `execFunction` to do the replace logic on each individual result if I query for a collection instead.

Is there a better (i.e. more performant) way to approach this?

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not a promise until you `.exec()` or `.then()` it. Until then, `connectionPromise` is actually a query! #namingthings

Comment: @joeytwiddle ah yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do conditional population with mongoose.

In your case, I think you are trying to do "deep population".

Deep population is not supported out of the box, but there is a plugin for that! [`mongoose-deep-populate`](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate)

```
const connectionQuery = Connection.findById( connectionId )
connectionQuery.populate( 'place event event.place' )
connectionQuery.exec( execFunction );
```

I'm guessing that `'place event.place'` will probably do it: `'event'` should be implied.

I also expect that, if `place` or `event` or `event.place` are undefined, there won't be an error, they simply won't be populated.

But I don't think there is any way, in one line, to skip populating `place` when `event.place` is available.

---

By the way, if you want to use promises, you could write like this:

```
return Connection.findById( connectionId )
    .populate( 'place event event.place' )
    .then( onSuccessFunc );
```

to propagate errors, or:

```
Connection.findById( connectionId )
    .populate( 'place event event.place' )
    .then( onSuccessFunc )
    .catch( onErrorFunc );
```

to handle errors locally.  I find that preferable to callbacks, because we don't have to worry about `if (err)` at every stage.